# How to fix crash issue on /data/app/com.android.chrome-...==/base.apk

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview

How to fix crash issue?

Firebase Crashlytic does not show this crash... But Play console thus.

My app have webview and admob.

Many Many thanks.

```
signal 5 (SIGTRAP), code 1 (TRAP_BRKPT)
```

[image]